# HDD connector for laptop hardidsk to PC

Tags: hard-disk, data-storage, sata

[image: Hard Disk port]
This is the Laptop's Hard Drive That I want to connect to my PC.
[image: My Existing SATA Cable]
This is the existing Hard Drive Cables in my PC.
Which Cables Should I purchase to connect HDD to my PC ?

Comment: It's hard to tell from the picture - could it be a PATA connector? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA

Answer (score 1):

That's a custom connector, specific to your brand of laptop. It should be possible to pull it off to reveal SATA power and data connectors underneath, which will work with your existing cables.