# Connector for HDD

Tags: hard-disk

I have this HDD from an old laptop I no longer possess and I would like to retrieve the data that's on it. I was wondering what kind of connector I would need to connect it to my PC. I saw another similar [here](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7269/hdd-connector-for-laptop-hardidsk-to-pc) but I am not quite sure I understand the solution that is given and if it is applicable to my own HDD.

Here is a picture:

[image: HDD]

and another one:

[image: top hdd]

Comment: Can you also post a picture from above? It would allow us to read the sticker.

Comment: Done. Sorry, for some reason the uploading tilt the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HDD is a Western Digital Scorpio Blue WD5000BEVT 500GB. In the first picture it seems that the HDD is wrapped in something. If this is the case, remove this piece.

You can read your HDD's full specs on [cnet](https://www.cnet.com/products/wd-blue-wd5000bevt-hard-drive-500-gb-sata-300-series/specs/) or [newegg](https://www.cnet.com/products/wd-blue-wd5000bevt-hard-drive-500-gb-sata-300-series/specs/).

Its interface is SATA 3 Gb/s - 7 pin Serial ATA. Looks for this in your favorite vendor.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So basically,  I need to look for a 7+15 pin Serial ATA (there are 7 pins + 15 pins - see first picture)?